# Cloudwatch with Serilog console sink showing in single cloudwatch entry with dotnet lambda

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serilog

I am trying to use Serilog console sink to write to cloudwatch. Yet when using Log.Information or Log.Error they are appearing in cloudwatch as one entry.

Additionally, an exception trace will show as separate entries.
I have tried changing the output template but this hasn't worked for info the serilog config is

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] <{SourceContext}> {Message:lj}\r{Exception}"
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
```

}

[Serilog log entries in same cloudwatch log event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3sFu.png)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; Don't use the Console sink for that. Use the [AWS.Logger.SeriLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWS.Logger.SeriLog/) sink instead.

---

The Console sinks is not the right tool for this job and you are not really sending logs to CloudWatch at the moment... You're just sending text. You're writing text to the Console and the raw console output is being captured by your environment and are then being forwarded to ClowdWatch as text as they get written to the output stream...

In order to properly send Serilog logs to AWS CloudWatch, you need to use a sink that will write logs to AWS CloudWatch directly, such as [AWS.Logger.SeriLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWS.Logger.SeriLog/) which is the official sink supported by AWS.

```
AWSLoggerConfig configuration = new AWSLoggerConfig("Serilog.ConfigExample");
configuration.Region = "us-east-1";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.AWSSeriLog(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

The source code repo is https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#serilog
and there are usage examples on https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/tree/master/samples/Serilog